# Как пробросить порты 22 и 80 на разные VM?

Tags: сеть, ssh, proxy, apache2, dns

Есть Windows Server, на котором через Hyper-V установлены 2 виртуальные машины. Ubuntu и Ubuntu Server.
Роутер не умеет открывать один и тот же порт на разные IP, потому хочу открыть порты 80(для домена) и 22(SSH) для Windows Server, а там нужно как то настроить, что бы перенаправляло в нужное русло.
Как это можно сделать? Не понимаю как правильно настроить DNS или IIS.
На VM стоят apache2 и SSH open server и в целом всё работает, если прокидывать порты отдельно, но работает, только что то одно.